# node.js ReferenceError: server is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

The below code is from **server.js**, it's causing my server to crash with Error:

ReferenceError: server is not defined at Object. (C:\xampp\htdocs\api\src\server.js:17:18) at Module._compile (module.js:571:32) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10) at Module.load (module.js:488:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3) at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10) at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7) at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9) at bootstrap_node.js:533:3

```
var express = require('express');
var body_parser = require('body-parser');
var app = express()

// Port config
var port = 3000;

app.use(body_parser.json());

// Use prefix of api
app.use('/api', require('../routes/api.js')(express));

app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server Active on', port);
});

module.exports = server;
```

Mocha testing (**__app.js**)

```
var request = require('supertest');

describe('API', function() {

var server;

beforeEach(function () {
  server = require('../src/server.js');
});

afterEach(function () {
  server.close();
});

it('/ should return specified object.', function (done) {
  request(server)
    .get('/api/')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(200, {"hello": "world"}, done);
});

it('/status should return specified healthy:true', function (done) {
  request(server)
    .get('/api/status')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(200, {"healthy": true}, done);
});

it('/user/id should return user object with id.', function (done) {
  var fakeUserID = 374;
  request(server)
    .get('/api/user/347' + fakeUserID)
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(200, {user: {id: fakeUserID}}, done);
  });
});
```

Am I missing a package? I'm watching a video with the same exact code and it doesn't crash the server.

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious: You are trying to assign `server` to `module.exports`, but the variable `server` doesn't exist. What do you expect `server` to be? Why are you exporting something from that module at all? Simplest example to reproduce the error: Put `module.exports = foo;` into a file and run it. It will complain that `foo` is not defined. This has nothing to do with Node, nvm, express or any library. It's just how JavaScript works: You cannot read a variable doesn't exist.

Comment: I know, I get that. However, it is working on what I'm watching with the exact same code, so there's something going on.

Comment: *"it is working on what I'm watching"* Either `server` is defined there somewhere or they are not using `server`. Since we can't see the video, it's impossible for us to say. All we can say is that using `server` is the issue in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You want to export the `app`. No variable called `server` exists

`module.exports = app;`

You can then import the `app` elsewhere in your project using `require`

Answer (score 1):

`server` is not defined anywhere. As a guess, you probably want to change the last line to:

```
module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```js
const server = app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server Active on', port);
});
```

Comment: I don't think this alone will solve their issue Awais